# Problem returning double from a function in C++

Tags: c++, double, precision

I have a function like:

```
double foo(int a, int b)
{
    double r=a+b;
    return r/2.0;
}
```

when a= 10000 and b= 10001 It works fine. Returns 10000.5

But when a= 100000 b= 100001 It returns 100000

I have tested with other numbers also. It only works when integers are less than 6 digits.(without using setprecision at output)

I also tried this, but it didn't help.

```
double r= double(a+b);
```

Can anyone explain what's happening? If I use setprecision at the output, there's no probllem.

But, I have no control over when and how the output will be printed, I have to submit just this function. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Could you please show how exactly you tested this? If it's just based on outputting the values then there's no problem with the function, it's all about how it's shown in output. Your function works just fine and you don't have to care how the value is shown.

Comment: If using setprecision causes the extra digits to be printed, then that means that the correct value had been stored in the double the entire time. Changing the output formatting doesn't change the value, just how the value is converted into text.

Comment: No there is nothing you can do. You have no control over how the output is printed but you are asking for the output to be printed with more than six digits of precision. Obviously that is asking for the impossible. There is of course nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: @Peter I did this: double a2=a;
    double r= a2 +b; but it didn't worked.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I just used cout<<foo(a,b);

Comment: @TrevorGalivan Yes, I can understand that. But I am looking for some way in C++ to tell how the output needs to be shown. The problem is pretty weird though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C double or long double uses 6 digit precision in output by default. If you want to write 2000.007 it will give output 2000.01 which is rounded upto 6 digit. But in the memory it will have the correct value. So, the correct way of doing that will be

```
double foo(int a, int b)
{
    double r=a+b;
    cout<<setprecision(4)<<fixed;
    return r/2.0;
}
```

And when you use **setprecision()** and **fixed** the outputs will be formatted from that point forward to all the outputs until any further changes are made. 
So, if you don't want to change anything about the output style then I'm afraid you can't do anything about this.

EDIT: Working with doubles sometime seems to cause unexpected output. For example if you have something like

```
double c = 299792458;
double b = 299792450;
cout<<c<<" "<<b<<" "<<c-b;
```

It will output

```
2.99792e+008 2.99792e+008 8
```

Which is again rounded to 6 digits which is exactly how it should've happened. But as the 3rd output the result is correct.

Comment: This prints a value to console, which is not what OP wants. OP just wants to return the value, which does not require setprecision. Quote: "I have no control over when and how the output will be printed, I have to submit just this function."

Comment: I think the better way would be using ```cout.precision(8)```, or any number greater than default ```6``` to get result OP wants.

Comment: @TrevorGalivan You seem not to have understood the answer. It is implied that the result is already correct. In that case, no additional line would be necessary at all.

Comment: @TrevorGalivan Afaik that doesn't print anything to the console. .That's just one way to declare the stream manipulator. I could be wrong

Comment: @TamimEhsan Whups! You are correct, I misread. It still doesn't make sense to modify the precision of the output stream every time this function is called, if the purpose of this function is just to perform some calculations though.

Comment: I don't know how, this works in the case I stated. Thanks @TamimEhsan. But I think it may not work in case the number is printed using some other method.

Comment: Is not using this affects precision of other outputs as well? (Just curiosity)